# upload image from android to PHP server- how to use MultipartUploadRequest in 'net.gotev:uploadservice:4.6.0' - I have a code for version2.1

Tags: android, image, http, multipartform-data

In version 2.1 of 'net.gotev:uploadservice:' MultipartUploadRequest was used as below:

```
MultipartUploadRequest a = new MultipartUploadRequest(this,  Constants.UPLOAD_URL).
                    addFileToUpload(path, "image").
                    addParameter("name", name).
                    setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig()).
                    setMaxRetries(2).
                    startUpload(); //Starting the upload
```

However its usage is different in version 4.6.0. Can anybody help me in getting the latest code?

Also, I tried this->

```
 new MultipartUploadRequest(this, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .setMethod("POST")
                    //.setBearerAuth(token)
                    .addHeader("User-Agent", getString(R.string.app_name) + "/" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                    //.addParameter("privacy", String.valueOf(idPrivacy))
                    //.addParameter("nsfw", "false")
                    .addParameter("name", name)
                    .addParameter("commentsEnabled", "true")
                    .addParameter("downloadEnabled", "true")
                    .addParameter("waitTranscoding", "true")
                    //.addParameter("channelId", idChannel)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image")
                    //.setNotificationConfig((this,uploadId)->getNotificationConfig(uploadId))
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload();
```

But it throws IllegalArgumentException

I am trying to declare private UploadNotificationConfig getNotificationConfig, but failing. It is not taking void parameter.

```
private UploadNotificationConfig getNotificationConfig(void) {
        if (!displayNotification.isChecked()) return null;

        return new UploadNotificationConfig()
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload)
                .setCompletedIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload_success)
                .setErrorIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload_error)
                .setTitle(filename)
                .setInProgressMessage(getString(R.string.uploading))
                .setCompletedMessage(getString(R.string.upload_success))
                .setErrorMessage(getString(R.string.upload_error))
                .setAutoClearOnSuccess(autoClearOnSuccess.isChecked())
                .setClickIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class))
                .setClearOnAction(true)
                .setRingToneEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.1' inside build.gradle. In 2.1, there was crash (white list process), so, I upgraded to 4.6.0. As I could not get the code for 4.6.0. I tried with 3.1. But there was foreground process crash. I could solve this crash using 3.4.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, UploadStatusDelegate {
    private static final int REQUEST = 112;
    //storage permission code
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;


    //private AndroidPermissions mPermissions;
    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText editText;
    private EditText imageName;
    private EditText imagePath;
    private CheckBox displayNotification;
    private CheckBox autoDeleteUploadedFiles;
    private CheckBox autoClearOnSuccess;
    private CheckBox fixedLengthStreamingMode;
    private CheckBox useUtf8;

    //Image request code
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    //Bitmap to get image from gallery
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    //Uri to store the image uri
    private Uri filePath;

    private String path;

    private  String USER_AGENT ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Requesting storage permission
        //requestStoragePermission();

        //Initializing views
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        imageName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editImageName);
        imagePath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editImagePath);

        displayNotification = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.displayNotification);
        autoDeleteUploadedFiles = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.autoDeleteUploadedFiles);
        autoClearOnSuccess = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.autoClearOnSuccess);
        fixedLengthStreamingMode = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.fixedLengthStreamingMode);
        useUtf8 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.useUtf8);

        //Setting clicklistener
        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        USER_AGENT = getString(R.string.app_name) + "/" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }
        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST:
            case STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE:
            default: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //do here
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "The app was  allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "The app was not allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            path = getPath(filePath);
            imagePath.setText(path);
            showImage();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE};
                if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
                    imagePath.setText("SDK>23,has no permission");
                    uploadMultipart();

                } else {
                    //do here
                    imagePath.setText("SDK>23,has no permission");
                    uploadMultipart();

                }
            } else {
                //do here
                imagePath.setText("SDK<23");
                uploadMultipart();

            }

        }
    }

    private boolean hasPermissions(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && this != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        imageName.setText("editText.getText().toString().trim()");
        imagePath.setText(editText.getText().toString().trim());
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();

        }
    }

    private void uploadMultipart() {
        String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        imageName.setText(name);

        try {
            MultipartUploadRequest req = new MultipartUploadRequest(this, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image")
                    .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .setNotificationConfig(getNotificationConfig(name))
                    .setCustomUserAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .setAutoDeleteFilesAfterSuccessfulUpload(autoDeleteUploadedFiles.isChecked())
                    .setUsesFixedLengthStreamingMode(fixedLengthStreamingMode.isChecked())
                    .setMaxRetries(3);

            String uploadID = req.setDelegate(this).startUpload();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
            //showToast(exc.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
            //showToast("Missing some arguments. " + exc.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedURLException exc) {
            //showToast(exc.getMessage());
        }
        
    }

    private UploadNotificationConfig getNotificationConfig(String filename) {
        //if (!displayNotification.isChecked()) return null;

        return new UploadNotificationConfig()
                //.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload)
                //.setCompletedIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload_success)
                //.setErrorIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload_error)
                //.setTitle(filename)
                //.setInProgressMessage("getString(R.string.uploading)")
                //.setCompletedMessage("getString(R.string.upload_success)")
                //.setErrorMessage("getString(R.string.upload_error)")
                //.setAutoClearOnSuccess(autoClearOnSuccess.isChecked())
                //.setClickIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class))
                //.setClearOnAction(true)
                .setRingToneEnabled(true);
    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri) {
        return getPath4(uri);
    }

    private String getPath1(Uri uri) {
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());//create path from uri
        String path = file.getPath();
        return path;
    }
    private String getPath2(Uri uri) {
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());//create path from uri
        final String[] split = file.getPath().split(":");//split the path.
        String path = split[1];
        return path;
    }
    private String getPath3(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    private String getPath4(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }
    private void showImage(){
        show(2);
    }
    private void show(int i){
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                showImgFromBitmap();
                break;
            case 2:
                showImgFromFilePath();
                break;
            default:
                showImgFromBitmap();
                break;
        }
    }
    private void showImgFromBitmap() {
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void showImgFromFilePath() {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
        editText.setText("progress");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse, Exception exception) {
        editText.setText("error");
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
        String s = writer.toString();
        editText.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse) {
        editText.setText(serverResponse.getBodyAsString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
        editText.setText("cancelled");
    }

    public class Constants {
        public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "https://swulj.000webhostapp.com/upload.php";
        public static final String TEST_URL = "https://swulj.000webhostapp.com/test.php";
        public static final String IMAGES_URL = "https://swulj.000webhostapp.com/getImages.php";
    }
}
```

To solve foregroundprocess crash->

```
public class Initializer extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // setup the broadcast action namespace string which will
        // be used to notify upload status.
        // Gradle automatically generates proper variable as below.
        UploadService.NAMESPACE = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
        // Or, you can define it manually.
        //UploadService.NAMESPACE = "com.example.yourapp";
    }

}
```

In Manifest file->add (android:name=".Initializer") as below->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testimageuploadhttp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestImageUploadHTTP"
        android:name=".Initializer">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:hint="Name For Image"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonUpload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editImageName"
        android:hint="Image Name"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editImagePath"
        android:hint="Image Path"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/use_utf8_charset"
            android:id="@+id/useUtf8"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fixed_length_streaming_mode"
            android:id="@+id/fixedLengthStreamingMode"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/display_notification"
            android:id="@+id/displayNotification"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/auto_clear_on_success"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:id="@+id/autoClearOnSuccess" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/auto_delete_uploaded_files"
            android:id="@+id/autoDeleteUploadedFiles"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

PHP CODE:
upload.php:

```
<?php 
 
 //importing dbDetails file 
 require_once 'dbDetails.php';
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);


 
 //this is our upload folder 
 $upload_path = 'uploads/';
 
 $parent_folder = 'AndroidUploadImage/';
 
 //Getting the server ip 
 $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
 
 //creating the upload url 
 $upload_url = 'https://'.$server_ip.'/'.$parent_folder.$upload_path; 
 
 //response array 
 $response = array(); 
 echo "Hello"."<br>";
 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     echo "Hello Sandeep"."<br>";
 
 //checking the required parameters from the request 
 if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$w = "USE ".DB;

if ($conn->query($w) === TRUE) 
{
    //echo "database used successfully". "<br>";
} else
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
 
 
 //connecting to the database 
 //$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');
 
 //getting name from the request 
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 
 //getting file info from the request 
 $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
 
 //getting the file extension 
 $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];
 
 //file url to store in the database 
 $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;
 
 //file path to upload in the server 
 $file_path = $parent_folder.$upload_path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension; 
 echo "Hi"."<br>";
 
 //trying to save the file in the directory 
 try{
 //saving the file 
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],DOCROOT.$file_path);
 echo "Insert into DB"."<br>";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `MyImages` (`id`, `url`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$file_url', '$name');";
 
 //adding the path and name to database 
 if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
 echo "success"."<br>";
 //filling response array with values 
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['url'] = $file_url; 
 $response['name'] = $name;
 }
 //if some error occurred 
 }catch(Exception $e){
     echo "Exception"."<br>";
 $response['error']=true;
 $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
 }
 //displaying the response 
 echo json_encode($response);
 
 //closing the connection 
 mysqli_close($conn);
 }else{
 $response['error']=true;
 $response['message']='Please choose a file';
 }
 }
 
 
 //We are generating the file name 
 //so this method will return a file name for the image to be upload 

 function getFileName(){
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');
 $sql = "SELECT max(id) as id FROM MyImages";
 $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
 
 mysqli_close($con);
 if($result['id']==null)
 return 1; 
 else 
 return ++$result['id']; 
 }
 

?>
```

dbDetails.php:

```
<?php 
 define('HOST','localhost');
 define('USER','your_user_name');
 define('PASS','your_passwd');
 define('DB','your_db');
 define('DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
 ?>
```

create database running this script from browser, before running any of the above code:
image_db.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'dbDetails.php';
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$conn = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$w = "USE ".DB;

if ($conn->query($w) === TRUE) 
{
    //echo "database used successfully". "<br>";
} else
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

 $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyImages (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, url VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL UNIQUE,name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY(id))";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($res)
    {
    echo "New table created successfully". "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error. "<br>";
    }


/*if(mysqli_query($conn, "DROP TABLE MyImages"))
    {
        echo "table direction dropped". "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "table direction not dropped". "<br>";
    }*/




$conn->close();


ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();

?>
```

create a folder "AndroidUploadImage". Under this create another folder "uploads". This is the place where uploaded images are stored.